# How to add Google Calendar in the Calendar app with two-step authentication?

Tags: release-freya, release-loki, calendar

Is there a way to do the above without removing the two-step authentication ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by adding an app password that you are going to use in Calendar.

https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords